# Will Running A GNU Parallel Command With Variables Cause Conflict?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, unix, gnu-parallel

I think this comes down to me not fully understanding how the processes of GNU Parallel are divided. I looked up if using variables with GNU Parallel would conflict and I found very little to nothing online.

If I'm using a command like the following with parallel:

```
echo "$textdata" | parallel -j5 cat | for line in file; do var1=$(echo $line); var2=$(echo "$line" | grep -A 1); var3=$(echo "$line" | somecommand); echo "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"; done
```

Would it conflict by overriding each other when using the variable? Or, does it run in different processes and the same variable can be used?

In other words, would $var1, $var2 or $var3 get confused between different processes running in parallel?

Comment: Huh? **GNU Parallel** is never even going to see your variables as they are after the pipe symbol (`|`) and in a subsequent process that reads the output of **GNU Parallel**. What are you actually trying to do - just in plain English?

Comment: I'm trying to use variables in a while read command. I'm concerned that if those variables are running "in parallel" then it could get over-ridden or substituted incorrectly. Does that make more sense? Sorry if I'm not being clear, trying to describe.

Comment: here's a possible way to do that: `echo "$textdata" | parallel -j5 --pipe myscript.sh` and `myscript.sh` contains: `while read line; do...` this is fine if there aren't very many lines. if there are many lines, think of a way to script your task without `while read line` or it will definitely run slow.

Comment: Hi Webb, and that would avoid overlapping the variables?

Comment: yes, parallel would run 5 instances of `myscript.sh`, giving some of the lines to each one, and each instance's variables wouldn't overlap.

Comment: Please stop and take a step or two backwards. What are you actually trying to do in broad terms. Something like... *"I have 184,000 names in $textdata and the start of it looks like this. I want to split that into 5 equal sized chunks and within each chunk, in parallel, look up something in another file and match it with something else."*

Comment: It is usually useful to show a working non-parallelized example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then explain which step you would like to parallelize.

Comment: sorry, that should be: `parallel -j5 --pipe ./myscript.sh` (i forgot the `./`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else wanting to know if running variables in GNU parallel will overlap, simply just take the command, such as:

```
echo "$textdata" | parallel -j5 cat | for line in file; do var1=$(echo $line); var2=$(echo "$line" | grep -A 1); var3=$(echo "$line" | somecommand); echo "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"; done
```

And run the command as a script.sh:

```
for line in file; do var1=$(echo $line); var2=$(echo "$line" | grep -A 1); var3=$(echo "$line" | somecommand); echo "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"; done
```

Thus is would be:

```
echo "$textdata" | parallel -j5 /script.sh
```

Hope this helps anyone working with parallel and variables.